# How to print linked list using c++ recursion in object oriented form (OOP)

Tags: c++

i m just creating my on stack using linked list,but when i print elements using recursion it exit with random code in geany.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
class Stack
{
    public:
    Node* Top;
    void stack()
    {
        Top = NULL;
    }
    void pop()
    {
        if(Top == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"\nstack empty";
        }
        Top = Top->next;
    }
    
    void push(int data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = Top;
        Top = newNode;
    }
    
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if(Top == NULL)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        tem_print(Top);
    }
    
    void tem_print(Node* t_top)
    {
        if(t_top == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        tem_print(t_top->next);
        cout<<t_top->data;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.print();
    return 0;
}
```

i used a print() function inside it i called another temp print function which is used to print elements,**It works fine if i used iteration method to print**

output:
**freeze of 3sec**

*and prints this*

---

(program exited with code: -1073741819)

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Please share the output

Comment: No part of your code ever initializes a `Node` with `next` set to `NULL`, so your condition can never be true

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that you meant `void stack()` to be the constructor `Stack()` instead

Comment: in push funtion i initialized newNode->next = Top, where Top is null so when adding new node we automatically  set last node to null

Comment: `Top` is never NULL in your code because you never set it to be so

Comment: Thanks for your help @UnholySheep, yes i didn't initialized Top  = NULL and constructor was also declared incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing `Top` in your code, so the first time you read from it, you are invoking undefined behavior (UB). The result of a program with UB could be anything, including freezing for some time, or exiting with an error code.

This function:

```
void stack()
    {
        Top = NULL;
    }
```

looks suspiciously like a constructor. If so, you need to write:

```
Stack()
    {
        Top = NULL;
    }
```

or even better:

```
Stack() : Top(NULL) {}
```

In fact, you don't even need a constructor if you just initialize `Top` when you declare it inside the class.

---

Also, in your `pop` function, you are accessing `next` even if `Top` is `NULL`. Instead, you need an `else` statement:

```
void pop()
    {
        if(Top == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"\nstack empty";
        }
        else   // needed to avoid UB
            Top = Top->next;
    }
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G5GKe5).

---

Also, you should avoid using `NULL` in your code: use `nullptr` instead. Finally, please avoid using `using namespace std;`, it's a bad habit.

Comment: why did you deleted all the comments.. :D

Comment: I didn't delete them, as far as I recall :) I don't remember what the comments were about, but they get deleted if they are not relevant to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pop` function performs `Top = Top->next;` even if `Top == NULL`.

Comment: will be adding return statement. so it won't execute that line.

Comment: and thanks for helping and using your time to check it. :D